# why addEventListener click doesnt display dataset?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make this code work but when I click on the selected `.grid-element` the `addEventListener` doesnt do what it supposed to do (display the data-number on `.screen`).

```js
let display = document.querySelector(".screen");

let numberPress = document.querySelector(".grid-element");

numberPress.addEventListener("click", function(){

    display.innerHTML = numberPress.dataset.number;
});
```

```html
<div class="screen">0</div>
<div class="grid-container">
   <button class="grid-element" data-number>7</button>
   <button class="grid-element" data-number>8</button>
   <button class="grid-element" data-number>9</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add your eventListener to each grid-element, not just the first one (use querySelectorAll + a loop). You also need to assign a value to your `data-number` attributes, such as `data-number="7"`

Comment: querySelector() only returns one element.  Look at querySelectorAll().  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Or use event delegation and `event.target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because data-number has no value. I edited your js code little bit and change querySelector to querySelectorAll because you need to select multiple items.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".grid-element")
   .forEach((x) => x.addEventListener("click", function(){
       document.querySelector(".screen").innerHTML = x.dataset.number
   })
);
```

```html
<div class="screen">0</div>
<div class="grid-container">
   <button class="grid-element" data-number="7">7</button>
   <button class="grid-element" data-number="8">8</button>
   <button class="grid-element" data-number="9">9</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler per .grid-element:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".grid-element").forEach((gridElement) => {
  gridElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
    display.innerHTML = numberPress.dataset.number;
  });
});
```

Comment: It works but i need to add  a value to ```data-number``` attribute first. Like Nick Parson suggested.